# how can i transform datetime correctly to be able to use it as the title of my file?

Tags: python, string, file, datetime

This is my code. I want to be able to create a file with the name composed of the date of the day it is created but with this way it does not work.

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()

myFile=open(today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'),".txt","w")

myFile.close()
```

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to put `/` in filenames since it could be a different directory. Also, you can use `+` to add `".txt"` to the filename.

Comment: I don't think it will let you put `/` in the filename, it's likely failing silently. If you try to do it via finder/explorer it gives you an error, the same as a couple other characters. Just use `-` instead.

Answer (score 0):

for a text file use this (WT means for writing in text mode)

```py
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
myFile=open(f"{today.strftime('%m_%d_%Y')}.txt","wt")
myFile.close()
```

for a binary file use this (WB means for writing in binary mode)

```py
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
myFile=open(f"{today.strftime('%m_%d_%Y')}.bin","wb")
myFile.close()
```

for more advanced scenarios:

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
with open(f"{today.strftime('%m_%d_%Y')}.txt","wt") as myFile:
    do_something()
    # file close not needed this way
    # myFile holds the variable to access the file such as myFile.write
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myfile=open(date.today().strftime('%m%d%Y')+".ext","w")
```